# Calling methods which might throw inside catch

Tags: c#, .net

Let us say we have an external server which we use *(e.g.-telephony station, etc.)*. Also we have the next code:

```
try
{
   externalService.CreateCall(callParams);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   _log.Error("Unexpected exception when trying execute an external code.", ex);
   _callService.UpdateCallState(call, CallState.Disconnected, CallOutcome.Failed);
   throw;
}
```

Theoretically `UpdateCallState` could throw but we would hide this exception using that code and would treat only exceptions generated by `CreateCall` in a right way.

The question is, what is the right pattern for these situations so that we treat all the exceptions correctly?

Comment: Call it seperately. Do not nest the possible throable exception calls. It could complex your code and you wont be able to recover gracefully any state.

Comment: In that case you must hang up if the call creation failed for any reason. You have to call it.

Comment: What do you mean hang up? If the A call throws exception, then create a failure flag and then call B which could again throw any exception. If A call didnt, then do not call B cuz flag was not set. Nesting exceptions will be problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always nest another `try..catch` inside the first catch and deal with it appropriately.

```
try
{
   externalService.CreateCall(callParams);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   _log.Error("Unexpected exception when trying execute an external code.", ex);
   try
   {
       _callService.UpdateCallState(call, CallState.Disconnected, CallOutcome.Failed);
   }
   catch(Exception updateEx)
   {
       // do something here, don't just swallow the exception
   }
   throw; // this still rethrows the original exception
}
```

Comment: `UpdateCallState` will never be invoked if `CreateCall` doesn't throw exception

Comment: @L.B - And? It looks to me that that call *should* only be made if `CreateCall` fails (based on the params being passed being `CallOutcome.Fail`). Plus that's exactly how the OP's code originally worked. Try understanding the question before downvoting!

Comment: That's what the original code did as well. Mind you it would seem updatecallstate needed to be done on success as well, not in the question though.

Comment: @Jamiec But it looks to me that it should be called if the `CreateCall` succeeds.

Comment: @L.B, and this is OK in that situation, when telephony station is unvailable it is a normal behaviour to hear a signal of dailing call

Comment: @L.B - Again, you're making assumptions that the OP never asked about! It striikes me that the OP wants to `UpdateCallState` when the call succeeds, but s/he's not asking about that.

Comment: @Jamiec you'r are making assumptions too `It looks to me that that call should only be made....` I can always cancel my downvote if your assumption turns out to be correct one.

Comment: @L.B - So does the OP accepting this answer satisfy your requirement to remove your downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Break it up. Something like

```
if !TryCreateExternalCall(callParams)
{
  _log.Error("Unexpected exception when trying execute an external code.", ex);
  _callService.UpdateCallState(call, CallState.Disconnected, CallOutcome.Failed); 
}
else
{
  throw new ExternalServiceException(???);
}
```

TryCreateExternalCall should of course log the exception and stacktrace, before it swallows and returns false.

Comment: In this case you lost your first exception.

Comment: @Andrii Startsev - Sort of, does say log it at the bottom before swallow and return false. Thing is did the 2nd excption happen because the first did. If you called the problem code in the catch block somewyhere else, would it still blow chunks. At best all we can say is they could be related sometime, somewhen.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to throw exception in Catch block.

The `try, Catch` suggest that

```
 try
{
 //make some changes. If something goes wrong go to Catch.
}

Catch(exception)
{
 //I will clean the mess. Rollback the changes.
}
```

Catch the exception, only if you can handle the exception. Else bubble it up let the caller decide on what to do with the exception.

Answer (score -1):

You should catch the most specific exception first, followed by the most general exceptions.

```
try
{
   externalService.CreateCall(callParams);
}
catch (CreateCallExceptionType ccEx)
{       
   _callService.UpdateCallState(call, CallState.Disconnected, CallOutcome.Failed);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{       
   //do something
}
```

And then you could handle the UpdateCallState exception within the method.